# matrix to dataframe for easier 3D plotting

Tags: r

I have a matrix that was the output of the EuropeanOptionArrays function in the QuantLib package. This is the structure:

```
num [1:61, 1:33] 0.0109 0.0154 0.0215 0.0298 0.0409 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
..$ : chr [1:61] "600" "605" "610" "615" ...
..$ : chr [1:33] "0.128767123287671" "0.124798869319417" "0.12083061535116..
```

I would like to create a `2013 x 3` data frame instead of the above. I want it to look like this:

```
 Strike Price         Time to Maturity        Option Value 
   650                  .1287                 
   650                  .1247
   650                  .1208
   650                  .1168
   ...                   ...                   ....
```

Instead of how it looks now where the option values are not vectors:

```
               0.1287            0.1247            0.1208           .1168...  
 600        0.01089619       0.009433598       0.006943248       0.005897702       
 605        0.01539911       0.013421805       0.010021222       0.008577718       
 610        0.02153793       0.018894224       0.014303551       0.012334122        
 615        0.02982046       0.026323863       0.020195542       0.017539548       
 620        0.04088268       0.036306751       0.028214722       0.024673190       
 625        0.05551221       0.049585461       0.039014121       0.034343843 
 ...
```

Is there a simple solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: sorry 2013x3 dataframe. 2013 rows, 3 columns

Comment: Perfect. I used the persp function with matrix, but I wanted the data this way to play around with it in the rgl package. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you matrix is `mat`, you can choose either of the two:

```
dat1 <- cbind(expand.grid(Strike_Price = as.numeric(rownames(mat)),
                          Time_to_Maturity = as.numeric(colnames(mat))),
              Option_Value = as.numeric(mat))

dat2 <- cbind(expand.grid(Time_to_Maturity = as.numeric(colnames(mat)),
                          Strike_Price = as.numeric(rownames(mat))),
              Option_Value = as.numeric(t(mat)))
```

**Example**

```
set.seed(0)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(12), 3, 4)
rownames(mat) <- 1:3
colnames(mat) <- 11:14

#          11         12           13         14
#1  1.2629543  1.2724293 -0.928567035  2.4046534
#2 -0.3262334  0.4146414 -0.294720447  0.7635935
#3  1.3297993 -1.5399500 -0.005767173 -0.7990092
```

My code gives:

```
## dat1

#   Strike_Price Time_to_Maturity Option_Value
#1             1               11  1.262954285
#2             2               11 -0.326233361
#3             3               11  1.329799263
#4             1               12  1.272429321
#5             2               12  0.414641434
#6             3               12 -1.539950042
#7             1               13 -0.928567035
#8             2               13 -0.294720447
#9             3               13 -0.005767173
#10            1               14  2.404653389
#11            2               14  0.763593461
#12            3               14 -0.799009249

## dat2

#   Time_to_Maturity Strike_Price Option_Value
#1                11            1  1.262954285
#2                12            1  1.272429321
#3                13            1 -0.928567035
#4                14            1  2.404653389
#5                11            2 -0.326233361
#6                12            2  0.414641434
#7                13            2 -0.294720447
#8                14            2  0.763593461
#9                11            3  1.329799263
#10               12            3 -1.539950042
#11               13            3 -0.005767173
#12               14            3 -0.799009249
```

---

As I said in my comment, I am not sure why you want a data frame here. I would think a matrix to be perfect for making 3D plot. For example:

```
Strike_Price <- as.numeric(rownames(mat))
Time_to_Maturity <- as.numeric(colnames(mat))
persp(Strike_Price, Time_to_Maturity, mat)
##image(Strike_Price, Time_to_Maturity, mat)
##contour(Strike_Price, Time_to_Maturity, mat)
```